# Excel help - extract info from middle of cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Is it possible to take the words 'each', 'Any 2 for', 'kg', etc... out of these cells and put them into another cell... leaving only the **$x.xx** price so it can be sorted.

Examples for above are:

```
1)  $10.99 kg
2)  $16.00 each
3)  Any 2 for $32.019
```

And second part of the question if the first solution doesn't also work for this scenario - can I extract the **$x.xx** value after the word 'Save' in these examples:

```
4)  $11.00 each Save $3.00
5)  $2.87 each 20% off, Save $0.72 $1.15 per 100ml
```

Any help you can provide is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: There are ways to do this but before I start looking into this, to save time, can you explain what you've tried please.

Comment: Is the $32.019 a typo?  Do all prices include a decimal and cents?  Some descriptors come before the price and some after.  You want to save the descriptors in another cell or just extract the price to another cell?  If you want to save descriptors, do you care about preserving their position so the composite price can be "reassembled" (ex: two columns, one with prefixes, one with suffixes)?  Does a cell contain just a single dollar amount or is it a mix of examples 1-3 and 4-5?  If these are 2 different problems, it would be better as 2 questions because the solutions are different.

Answer (score 3):

> "put them into another cell... leaving only the $x.xx price"

You can't change your original cells in Excel with standard formulas, what you can do is to extract the price into a new cell / column.

To extract first `$..`:
`=MID(A1,FIND("$",A1),FIND(" ",A1,FIND("$",A1))-FIND("$",A1))`
This function looks for the first `$` and extract the text from that until the next space

To extract the number after `Save`:
`=MID(A5,FIND("Save",A5)+5,IFERROR(FIND(" ",A5,FIND("Save",A5)+5),LEN(A5)+1)-(FIND("Save",A5)+5))`
It works with similar logic but it finds after first `Save`

[image]

This solution works only if you have prices starting with `$` / `Save` and finished by a space or end of string, so it won't work if you have e.g. comma after the number, if you want to have more general solutions than there are free regular expression add-ins for Excel which provide regEx find capable worksheet functions. That would be your ultimate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("$",A1,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Save",A1)),SEARCH("Save",A1),1)),SEARCH(" ",A1&" ",SEARCH("$",A1))-SEARCH("$",A1))
```

Note: It works only if you have '$' before the value

Comment: what about second part of the question? in that case he can have multiple `$...` values and he is interested to get the one after "Save".

Comment: That is already figured in the formula. So it works for both the situations